# Проблема с обновлениями Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, обновление

Начиная с некоторого момента в пределах месяца (точнее сказать не могу) перестала работать служба обновления. Любые попытки ее запуска, поиска обновлений наталкиваются на

> Центр обновлений Windows в настоящее время не может выполнить поиск обновлений, поскольку эта служба не запущена. Возможно, потребуется перезагрузить компьютер.

Понятно, что перегрузка ничего не дает. Службы "Центр обновления Windows" и "Фоновая интеллектуальная служба передачи" работают. Перезапускал вручную - не помогает.

Ничего нового вроде бы не ставил, настройки не менял.

Windows 7 64-разрядная.

Та же ерунда на еще двух машинах дома - только и того, что там Windows 7 32-разрядная.

Грешил на какое-то обновление - попробовал снести последние обновления Windows - тоже не помогло. Обновления Office или Visual Studio не сносил.

Windows Update Troubleshooter скачивал, запускал. Копался, сказал, что все исправлено - но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: http://pc-problems.ru/win_vista_7/recovery_windows/218/ не пробовали?

Comment: *Начиная с некоторого момента в пределах месяца (точнее сказать не могу)* Откат в точку восстановления пробовал?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Спасибо! Оформите свой комментарий как ответ - чтобы я мог поблагодарить вас единственным доступным здесь способом :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Упс... При установке свежих обновлений что-то пошли отказы...

Comment: Вы же не всю пачку сразу выбрали, надеюсь, к установке? Или всю сразу? Сколько их было?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Нет, все нормально... извините за ложную тревогу. Ставил 3 шт. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вероятно, нарушились индексы в папке %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution. Удалять ее пока не нужно, лучше переименовать. [Подробный инструктаж, как это сделать](http://pc-problems.ru/win_vista_7/recovery_windows/218/). Если список вновь обнаруженных обновлений будет велик, не рекомендую устанавливать все скопом, - могут возникнуть противоречия, лучше устанавливать по нескольку за раз.